# LC_LOCALE settings interactions between Mac OSX and LINUX via SSH

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vim, emacs

I have been struggling with the following problem for years now. I have never been able to solve it, and I adopted several workarounds to keep being able to work. However now I can't stand it anymore, and I really would like to find a solution once and for all.

Here's the thing. I work on a MacBookPro with an AZERTY keyboard, but most of the time I plug to it a QWERTY Mac keyboard. Moreover, I need to connect to Linux remote machines via ssh.

As long as I use text editors that open in the terminal (emacs, vim), my keyboard is decently recognised, and I can't really complain about it. But if I try to use some other text editors that go through X11/XQuartz such as gedit or nedit, CRASH, disaster. They run, of course, but they're absolutely unable in any way to detect my plugged QWERTY keyboard.

So, what kind of environments variables am I supposed to set, and where? I am really sick of these problems, so any help would be the most welcome.

Comment: What don't you remove the jokes and give us more detail?

Comment: What kind of detail would be useful?